# Recording another computer's desktop

Tags: pi-4

Is there a way to use raspberry as a capture device to record audio and video of another pc?

Comment: yes, there is a way ... is that really all you want to know? ... the answer to almost all `is there a way?` questions is `yes`

Answer (score 1):

There is USB based dongles that can capture HDMI or VGA. And for sure Raspberry Pi can record a video stream.

Example:
[image: HDMI capture dongle]

And Im not sure if [PiKVM - Open and inexpensive DIY IP-KVM on Raspberry Pi](https://pikvm.org/) could help you on the way.